# Macro for power query

Tags: window

New here, I am trying to use macro into power query but I unable to run macro into power query editor.
What I am trying to do marge multiple sheet and want to upload data into one big file for daily task.
If any one know how to solve please let me know.

Thanks

What I am trying to do marge multiple sheet and want to upload data into one big file for daily task.
If any one know how to solve please let me know.

Thanks